# Express js call a request twice and once at the same time: so weird

Tags: post, request, express

```
var a = 0;
app.post('/rpc', function(req, res){
    debugger; // hits only once
    var console = require('console');
    a++; // runs once
    console.log(a); // runs twice!!!
    debugger; // hits only once
});
```

I'm really crazy about this. The console.log runs twice! and a++ and the rest only once...

Output it's:

```
1
1
```

Please any help?
thanks

Edit:

when I run my app like this

```
 supervisor -w .,services,models,test -- --debug index.js
```

it calls twice. If I call only

```
 node --debug index.js
```

it works just fine..

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up an additional instance of console (there is one there by default)
Have you tried removing your require console statement from the app.post block?

Normally, you should not need to add 'require console' as its there by default - unless you need it for some particular reason which I could not gather from the post.

hope it helps

Comment: yes, it works without the require, but continues to run twice. The problem also is: when I insert some record in the DB also tries to insert twice... :s

Comment: is that the case without the debug statement too?  also, have you tried using an older version of supervisor (in case you are using the latest one) to check if the behavior is the same